# can i use firebase to send notification even f i am offline

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, notifications, offline

I am new to flutter and i am trying to make a todo task app that will remind me of my tasks in there time but what if my user doesnt have internet..

so my app should remind him even if he is not connected.

i saw alot of things about local notification package for flutter..
but it doesn't work on all Android Devices for some reasons (READE.ME of the package)...

so my question is there anyway to push notification without internet (it would be better to push it without firebasee if its not possible).

thanks for everyone

Comment: Are you trying to make notifications appear as soon as he reconnects to an internet source or show local notifications based on events from within the app?

Comment: I am trying to make a reminder notification that pop up with at the time he did select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase sends remote notifications and you plug it into the native device notifications API.

So you can of course use another library to pop local notifications. I suggest this one: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

> A cross platform plugin for displaying and scheduling local notifications for Flutter applications with the ability to customise for each platform.

It's a widely used library with a ton of users and documentation available.

Comment: Is his can be achieved with out internet connection?? I just need to be connected to the wifi

Comment: With this library you can generate offline push notifications. So from within the app, like if you create an event or meeting inside an app and set a due-date or alike. Then you can queue the notification to pop 24/03/2021 at 16:40:00.

Comment: I just read your other comment. This library will allow you to do that indeed. You just instantly queue the notification when he sets the time in your app.